# Convert char type '0'-'9' to int type and print to stdout in C language

Tags: c, char, int, stdout

I write a program to receive user input and print it out to screen.

The sample input is `abc 12 34`.

The sample output is `abc 12 34`, but the `12` and `34` should be input as integer.

With sample input, my program always output as `abc 122 344` . I have been working on it for a long time, but I still can't figure it out. Could help me check my code please? Thanks.

My gcc version is 4.1.2 .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    char *str = NULL;
    str = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char)); /*just sample code, not robust*/
    memset(str,'\0',20*sizeof(char)); 

    if(str == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: failed to allocate memory.\n"); fflush(stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    /*store user input*/
    int index = 0;
    while((c=getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        *(str+index) = c;
        index++;
    }

    int digit = 0;
    for(index = 0; *(str+index)>0; index++)
    {
        if((*(str+index)>='a') &&( *(str+index)<='z'))
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"%c",*(str+index)); fflush(stdout);
        }

        else if((*(str+index)>='0') &&( *(str+index)<='9'))
        {
            /*handling the case that a number with more than one digit*/
                    if(*(str+index+1)>='0' && *(str+index+1)<='9')
            {
                digit=10*(digit+atoi(str+index));
            }
            else
            {
                digit += atoi(str+index);   
                fprintf(stdout,"%d",digit); fflush(stdout);
                digit = 0;
            }           
        }

        else
        {   
            fprintf(stdout,"%c",*(str+index)); fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two quick changes for you.

First, as already noted, `atoi()` take a string and return an int. Since you're just doing 1 character (0-9) just subtract it from the character '0'.

```
digit=10*(digit+(*(str+index)-'0')); //instead of atoi(str+index)
```

Why subtract '0'? It comes down to the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of numbers.

The value of the character '0' is 30<sub>10</sub>, the value of '1' is 31<sub>10</sub>, so:

```
int a = '0' - '0'; // that's  30-30, or 0 as an int
int b = '1' - '0'; // that's  31-30, or 1 as an int
```

If you make this tweak in both places you're currently using `atoi()`:

```
            ...
            digit=10*(digit+atoi(str+index));
        }
        else
        {
            digit += atoi(str+index); 
            ...
```

Changes to:

```
            ...
            digit=10*(digit+(*(str+index)-'0'));
        }
        else
        {
            digit += *(str+index)-'0';   
            ...
```

Your code will now work the way you want it to. One more point, you have an `if`/`if else`/`else` checking for a-z, 0-9, then anything else.

Because your first `if` and your `else` are identical code it means there's a simplification that can be done there. Just removing the entire first `if` and changing your `else if` to just an `if` will give you the exact same thing as what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. I really appreciate your explaination about `digit=10*(digit+(*(str+index)-'0'));`@Mike

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `atoi`: it converts a string to `int`, not a single `char`.

Here is what happens: when you see a two-digit number, say, `34`, the first iteration pssses both digits to `atoi`, gets `34`, and multiplies it by ten, making `340`. The following iteration picks up `4`, and happily adds it to `340`, for the cumulative result of `344`.

If you would like to convert a single `char` that represents a digit to an `int`, use subtraction:

```
digit = *str - '0';
```

Moreover, your code for handling multi-digit numbers is, well, unorthodox, making it hard to understand. Instead of multiplying the *current* value by ten when you see that the next character is a digit, you should multiply the *prior* value by ten when you see a digit. This works even for the first digit, when the prior value is `0`, because ten times zero is still a zero.

You should eliminate the `if(((*str+index+1)>='0') && (*str+index+1)<='9')` and its `then` branch, and modify its `else` branch as follows:

```
digit = 10*digit + *(str+index) - '0';
if (((*str+index+1)<'0') || (*str+index+1)>'9') {
    fprintf(stdout,"%d",digit); fflush(stdout);
    digit = 0;
}
```

Comment: `your code is not going to work for multi-digit numbers` - I think the code, as is, (minus the `atoi` issue) does work for multi-digit numbers. ex: given "102 ", first pass in the if: `digit = 10`, second pass in the if: `digit = 100`, third pass in the else `digit = 102` and it's  printed. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mike Ah, you're right, I think the result would work out to the same number. Still, it's a really unorthodox implementation; I fixed the wording of the answer to reflect your comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks a lot. Now, I know it's my misuse of atoi() that leads to this confusing problem. Another mistake in my code is that `if (((*str+index+1)<'0') || (*str+index+1)>'9')` should be `if (*(str+index+1)<'0' || *(str+index+1)>'9')`. I'll edit it right now.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using `sscanf` for that ? like this:

```
sscanf(str, "%s %d %d", str1, &num1, &num2);
```

If you can't use `sscanf`, for some reason, then you should at least use `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` to check for characters and numbers, respectively.

So instead of using this:

```
if((*(str+index)>='a') &&( *(str+index)<='z')) {
    .....
}
```

Use this:

```
if (isalpha(*str+index)) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing another elegant solution to this question. @mux